# Please help me to understand this email message

Tags: meaning

I have received a message from a company I applied for but I do not know if they meant a polite rejection or still in process.

> Thank you for your application.Due to the volume of applications that we receive, only selected candidate(s) will be contacted. Further, we are unable to provide specific feedback on your application, or recommendations for improvement.We appreciate your time and effort in submission of your application for our review and wish you well in your future endeavours.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a dual purpose email. If you are not a selected candidate, you will not be contacted again, hence they "wish you well in your future endeavours".

It says "only selected candidates **will be** contacted". The use of "will be" rather than "have been" and the reference to a large volume of applications implies the people going forward have not been selected yet.